# How to add items to a listbox in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have the following listbox and would like to add drivers and their versions into it. As of now, nothing is being added and I get a "Cannot find an overload for "Add" and the argument count: "1"" error.

```
#Driver List

$ListBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView

$ListBox1.Location  = New-Object System.Drawing.Point(150,180)

$ListBox1.AutoSize = $true

$ListBox1.Scrollable = $true

$ListBox1.Text = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select DeviceName, Manufacturer, DriverVersion | ForEach-Object {[void] $ListBox1.Items.Add($_)} 

$main_form.Controls.Add($ListBox1)


    }
)
```

Comment: Remove `$ListBox1.Text = `. The `Text` property isn't relevant for `ListView`, use just `.Items.Add()`. You will propably want to construct a `ListViewItem` to be passed to `.Add()` so you can specify the properties `DeviceName`, `Manufacturer` and `DriverVersion` as sub items.

Comment: Thanks for the info, would you mind expanding on this as I'm still navigating my way around Powershell? 

I understand that .text is not a part of the ListView property now. As far as constructing the listviewitem, am I on the right track with the below?

$ListBox1.Items.Add = Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| select DeviceName, Manufacturer, DriverVersion

Comment: Sorry, I don't have time for a full-fledged answer. Re your last code sample. Still not right. Something more like: `Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| ForEach-Object { $item = [Windows.Forms.ListViewItem]::new(); $item.Text = $_.DeviceName; $item.SubItems.Add($_.Manufacturer); $item.SubItems.Add($_.DriverVersion); $listBox1.Items.Add($item)`. Before that works, you need  to switch ListView into details view (`$listBox1.View='Details'`) and defines the 3 columns (`$listBox1.Columns.Add('...')`).

Comment: Thanks! will try out your suggestion and see where that gets me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very rough working example below.

Iterate through the drivers, adding one at a time:

```
# main form
$main_form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$main_form.Text = "Test"
$main_form.Size = '830,445'
$main_form.StartPosition = 'CenterScreen'

# Add Listview    
$ListBox1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListView
$ListBox1.Location  = '20,20'
$ListBox1.Size = '780,380'
$ListBox1.Scrollable = $true
$listBox1.View='Details'
# Add the columns you want to the listbox
$ListBox1.Columns.Add('DeviceName',120) | Out-Null
$ListBox1.Columns.Add('Manufacturer',120) | Out-Null
$ListBox1.Columns.Add('Version',120) | Out-Null
   
$main_form.Controls.Add($ListBox1)

# Anything in this section will be performed after form is visible rather than before
$main_form.add_Shown({ 

Get-WmiObject Win32_PnPSignedDriver| ForEach-Object { 
# Make sure there's a devicename present
    If ($_.DeviceName) {
#Entry first column is devicename
        $Entry = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItem($_.DeviceName)
# Try next field
        Try {
            $Entry.SubItems.Add($_.Manufacturer) | Out-Null
        }
        Catch {
# Put in placeholder if field is empty
            $Entry.SubItems.Add("-")
        }
        Try {
# Try next field
            $Entry.SubItems.Add($_.DriverVersion) | Out-Null
        }
        Catch {
# Put in placeholder if field is empty
            $Entry.SubItems.Add("-")
        }
# Add the device entry to the listview
        $listBox1.Items.Add($Entry)
    }
}
    
# Resize columns to content
$ListBox1.AutoResizeColumns(1) 
})
# Show form
$main_form.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```